# Выполнить действие после выполнения всего метода

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот у меня есть метод `"download"`, который скачивает файлы типа `"А"` с FTP сервера, и есть метод `"upload"`, который загружает файлы типа `"В"` на тот же сервер. Как сделать чтобы метод `upload` начинал выполнятся строго после того, как выполнится метод `download`?

Сейчас вообще совершено не понятно почему, `upload` может внезапно начать загружать файлы, во время скачивания.

P.S. файлов типа `А` и `В` может быть разное количество.

Сейчас делаю так:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    download();
    upload();
 }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста реально рабочий способ! 
Всем большое спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Вангую методы асинхронны и выполняются в другом потоке

Comment: Что я должен сделать, чтобы они стали последовательными?)

Comment: Либо переписать код так, чтобы методы `download` и `upload` выполнялись синхронно, либо самому написать код ожидания завершения работы метода, либо попробовать использовать для этого стандартные средства языка.

Comment: С сервера надо получить ответ, что все файлы переданы. После этого делать `upload`

Comment: Каким образом я получу ответ? Сервер ведь сам по себе ничего не отдает

Comment: @YuriGo Покажите, что у вас внутри ваших методов download и upload

Comment: В вашем коде upload начнет выполнятся строго после того, как выполнится метод download. Если наблюдается обратное - приведите минимальный пример для воспроизведения проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Если методы `download()` и `upload()` сами по себе асинхронны и поддерживают ожидание, то тогда следующий код

```
public async void MyMethod()
{
   //код до первого await будет выполнен синхронно в основном потоке
   await download();//ждем выполнения асинхронной операции в фоновом потоке
   //код между первым и вторым await будет выполнен синхронно в основном потоке
   await upload();//ждем выполнения асинхронной операции в фоновом потоке
   //возвращаемся в основной поток
}
```

Comment: если download и upload уже содержат асинхронные операции, то текущий подход не поможет